# Set a non-column property value in Linq to SQL query

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Is there any way to set a property that is not generated by Linq to SQL designer (is not a column in database) in a query?

For example is there such a method like SomeMethod():

```
IQuaryable<T> query = (from t in context.MyTable
                      where {some conditions}
                      select t).SomeMethod("MyPropertyName", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
var query = (from t in context.MyTable
                  where {some conditions}
                  select new {t, MyPropertyName = value });
```

im not sure if this is what you're asking or not.