# How to use UDF output as LINQ to SQL entity class property value?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, designer, user-defined-functions

Just starting out with LINQ to SQL (you can probably tell - be gentle).

I'd like to **use the value returned by a user-defined function as an entity class property value** and have the the value populated when all the other basic (column) fields are loaded.

I know there are ways to use the UDF from a L2S query ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281210/is-it-possible-to-use-access-scalar-functions-with-linq-to-sql), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480152/set-a-non-column-property-value-in-linq-to-sql-query)), but I'd prefer to have the value automatically loaded.

For example, I'd expect LINQ to SQL to generate SQL similar to this and populate a property on my User entity class called AssociatedRecordCount with the integer value returned by GetAssociatedRecordCount:

```
SELECT ID, dbo.GetAssociatedRecordCount(ID) As AssociatedRecordCount
FROM Users
```

Also, I'm using the Visual Studio LINQ to SQL designer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a new custom property not associated with the database and call the function (added to the context) in the getter.

Comment: Thanks Devart.  What I really want is to have the UDF generated value pre-loaded when I get the entity object from the database as my application will disconnect the object from the datacontext during remoting serialization.  But I don't think there's a way to do that and I think your answer is as close as I'll get.